# Least square fit for data with uncertainty

Tags: statistics, least-squares

I have a set of data $\{x_i,y_i\}$ that came from my measurement, so each of them has some uncertainty. I wonder is there a method to fit them using a model (like Gaussian), while taking care of those uncertainties? In my previous experience on the least-squares fit, I only used the data and didn't take uncertainties in measurement into account. Thanks:)

Comment: See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares
and, more generally, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models

Comment: @Max Thank you!